# Network.DownloadFile -- Not registering 404 when redirected to HTTPS

Tags: vb.net, apache, ssl, redirect

So I will admit, I attempted to search for this issue with  no luck as I'm not really sure exactly WHAT to search for - mostly because I'm not sure if the issue is with VB.NET or Apache.

**The Short Version:** When getting a 404 from Network.DownloadFile, the 404 is NOT caught if I attempt to load the document from an http://* address and Apache redirects it to an https://* address. Instead, VB.NET downloads the 404 page to a .png file.

If I attempt to load it from https://* and Apache doesn't need to redirect the request, the 404 DOES get caught. If I attempt to load it from http://* and Apache does NOT redirect me to https://*, the 404 DOES get caught.

I have verified that Apache is serving the SAME 404 page in all instances.

**Code Example:**

```
Try
    'TRY to download the file using https first...
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(New Uri("https://" & ServerAddress & WebLogoPath & Convert.ToString(RowArray(0)) & ".png"), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\" & AppDataFolder & PCLogoPath & Convert.ToString(RowArray(0)) & ".png", "", "", False, 500, True)
Catch ex_https As Exception
    'Unable to locate file or write file
    'If the operation timed out...
    If (ex_https.Message = "The operation has timed out") Then
        'Re-TRY to download the file using http instead, as a time out error may indicate that HTTPS is not supported.
        Try
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(New Uri("http://" & ServerAddress & WebLogoPath & Convert.ToString(RowArray(0)) & ".png"), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\" & AppDataFolder & PCLogoPath & Convert.ToString(RowArray(0)) & ".png", "", "", False, 500, True)
        Catch ex_http As Exception
            'Most likely, the file doesn't exist on the server. Either way, we cannot obtain the file so we need to perform the same action, 
            'which is handled outside of this Try block.
        End Try
    Else
        'This is most likely a 404 error. Either way, we cannot obtain the file (and the connection is not timing out) - so
        'we need to perform the same action, which is handled outside of this Try block.
    End If
End Try
```

The code above is a work-around solution to this problem; however, it is horribly inefficient as I now have to wait for each timeout period (500ms). This may not seem like a large deal - but this is all in a For Loop that needs to check for X files - meaning each check can take up to 1 second to complete. In the end, if my loop is processed 100 times - that's a potential of almost 2 minutes to wait.

If possible, I would like to cut this in half by only having it attempt to load the image from http://* and catching the 404 if the request gets redirected to https://* or not.

**More Information:** I could just standardize the methods used by Apache and my code. However, this is all connected to data hosted from 2 different servers (the data is duplicated between them). One server supports AND FORCES SSL, the other does not. I'm not looking for a solution that involves changing SSL rules on either server. I'm only looking for a solution that result in VB.NET properly reporting a 404 error when one occurs.

I strongly feel like this is a bug in VB and not Apache, but I could be wrong. I only suggest that as I can confirm that Apache is serving the exact same file no matter what. The only factor that affects VB is if the request gets redirected from http://* to https://*

Comment: What you experience is not a bug. All built-in download methods require a **direct URL** to the file to be downloaded, as they download whatever the URL points to. They were not designed to deal with redirects. See the suggested duplicate for a solution (the part below **EDIT** in my answer).

Comment: Well, I guess I can accept that it is not a bug - and I figured I might have to use an HttpWebRequest - I was just trying to avoid it if possible (just to be lazy, really). But at the least, with how common redirects are, wouldn't this at least be considered a limitation?

Also, I don't see anywhere in the documentation that states that redirects are not supported in this method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127878(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Either way, the 'DownloadFileWithRedirect' method you proposed works great and solves the problem. I'll mark that as the answer in the end - I just want to leave this open for a little bit to see if anybody can answer why this limitation may exist or is not documented.

Comment: `I don't see anywhere in the documentation that states that redirects are not supported` - There is no reason for the documentation to mention that. The method does exactly what the docs say it would do: `Downloads the specified remote file and saves it in the specified location`. If the nothing exists at the specified URL then it'll throw an error, if something does exist then it'll download that.

Comment: And something does exist (or at least at the time of the request): Apache's 404 error document. It gets the error document (which is a file) as a response, and thus downloads it. Nothing strange about it. -- The built-in method doesn't check the response's HTTP code and therefore it cannot adapt to redirections.